# Save to Hive Partitioned Table using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The Spark 1.4.0 and higher source code seems to indicate the subject of this post were not possible (except in Spark specific format).

```
def saveAsTable(tableName: String): Unit = {

  * When the DataFrame is created from a non-partitioned [[HadoopFsRelation]] with a single input
   * path, and the data source provider can be mapped to an existing Hive builtin SerDe (i.e. ORC
   * and Parquet), the table is persisted in a Hive compatible format, which means other systems
   * like Hive will be able to read this table. Otherwise, the table is persisted in a Spark SQL
   * specific format.
```

I was wondering if there were systematic workarounds for this. Any hive table worth its salt **will** be partitioned - for scalability and performance reasons. Therefore this is the *normal* usecase not a corner case.